# Errors in new Template10 Blank app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal, template10

I tried a new blank app for Template10.
The first thing that comes up is a web page that gives some sort of supplimentary instructions as to why the app has 163 errors.

I don't understand what it is trying to say, nor how to clear the errors.  Somethign about control q? That does nothing. Is the app running when you press that?  Is there some non-shortcut way to make sense of this?  Why are the errors there in the first place..

https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Welcome-%7C-Blank-Template

Hit  F5  right now and run your new app! To refresh Visual Studio's intellisense, follow this:

1. Press Ctrl+Q, type  pac man gen
2. Ensure  Allow NuGet to download missing packages  is checked.
3. Ensure  Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio  is checked.
4. Right-click your Solution, and select  Clean
5. Right-click your Solution, and select  Rebuild
6. Select your project, and click the  Refresh  button at the top of Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case I had only the 10586 SDK.
Template 10 use both 10240 and 10586 SDK (if you want), I always check the 10586 SDK option, however I think that this is broken so I can fix it if I do this:

1. I clean the project
2. I go to Project Properties => Application => minimum version and select 10240.
3. I implement the project. You will see that some references have been added.
4. I go to Project Properties => Application => minium version and select 10586
5. I build and run the project

I hope this can help you

Comment: I tried creating the project as the 10240. That still left 21 errors, but it did seem to add the References. It still wont run.  I will try writing to Nixon. Thanks.

Comment: Nixon never wrote back.  Kind of disappointing. Cant use it if it doesn't work.